# Can I do Buy any 2 for $100?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Is it possible to create a shopping cart price rule - for a particular category, Any 2x from (category created) for $100?

Answer (score 0):

Go to shopping cart price rule and add new one.

In Condition part: Choose your category like this:

[image]

And in your Action Part: Set config as bellow:

[image]

**You are allowing to apply the coupon for max of 2 qt and discount applies when only item's qty is 2. And then it will get 50% discount.**

Unfortunately you will have to work around to get discount %, it will not be exact $100.